# testcafe - CAS authentication

Tags: authentication, testing, automated-tests, cas, testcafe

New to TestCafe. Got some simple example tests working easily. However, I wasn't able to find any examples of features that would seem to allow me to log in to my application via a CAS authentication page.

This code works to find the login button on the login page and click it.

```
fixture`VRT`
    .page `http://myapp.com/login/`;

test('Find Login button', async t => {
    const input = Selector('input.btn');

    await t.click(input);
});
```

And this would work to type in the username and password on the login page:

```
test('Login using CAS', async t => {
     await t
     .expect("#username").exists
     .typeText('#username', 'myuser')
     .typeText('#password', '***')
     .click('#submit');
});
```

But the problem is that there seems to be no way to continue from one test to another. So I can't go from the first test that opens the login page, to the next test that enters the credentials. It seems like, for TestCafe, every test has to specify its own page.

If I try to go to the CAS login page directly, by specifying it as the fixture "page", TestCafe fails to open the page, I think because the URL is extremely long.

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

Update:

So, using roles got me a bit further (thanks) but had to get through one more CAS page with an input button to click before getting to the page I wanted to test. Was able to add in another click to the role login:

```
import { Role } from 'testcafe';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const finalLoginBtn = Selector('input.btn');

const myUserRole = Role('http://example.com/login', async t => {
    await t
        .click('input.btn')
        .typeText('#username', 'my-username')
        .typeText('#password', '*****')
        .click('#submit')
        .click(finalLoginBtn);
}, { preserveUrl: true });

fixture`VRT`

test("My User Page", async t => {
    await t.navigateTo(`http://example.com`)
    await t.useRole(myUserRole);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The TestCafe 'User Roles' functionality should suit your requirements. Please, refer to the following topic in the TestCafe documentation for details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html